# what does maxIdleTime setting mean in jetty

Tags: jetty

I am working on a existing Jetty Application where it has been  configured with  maxIdleTime inside the Application .

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.UserServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>maxIdleTime</param-name>
           <param-value>300000</param-value>
      </init-param>
     </servlet>
```

**As per the Jetty documentation it means that** but i could not understand what does that mean ?? Could anybody please let me know . Thanks in advance .

```
Set the maximum Idle time for a connection, which roughly translates to the Socket.setSoTimeout(int) call, although with NIO implementations other mechanisms may be used to implement the timeout. The max idle time is applied: when waiting for a new request to be received on a connection; when reading the headers and content of a request; when writing the headers and content of a response. Jetty interprets this value as the maximum time between some progress being made on the connection. So if a single byte is read or written, then the timeout (if implemented by jetty) is reset. However, in many instances, the reading/writing is delegated to the JVM, and the semantic is more strictly enforced as the maximum time a single read/write operation can take. Note, that as Jetty supports writes of memory mapped file buffers, then a write may take many 10s of seconds for large content written to a slow device.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context that you mention above, as an init param to a user servlet, it has nothing to do with Jetty.  It is simply a parameter being passed to that servlet and it is entirely up to that servlet on what it will do with it.

Within jetty do you set something like max idle time to a connector then it is how long that that connector will be allowed to remain idle with no traffic before it is shutdown with an idle timeout.

Comment: This configured UserServlet  extends Jetty's WebSocketServlet  , and this WebSocketServlet extends HttpServlet , and where as HttpServlet  has not got any relation with maxIdleTime ?? so i guess this maxIdleTime  is related to Jetty itself .

Comment: Aw, you left that bit out!  Javadoc of websocket servlet says - The initParameter "maxIdleTime" can be used to set the time in ms that a websocket may be idle before closing.